# Laravel RouteKeyName field is ambiguous in Model instance with joined tables

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, routes, slug

Anyone have some ideas on how to resolve an issue using slugs for Laravel routeKeyName in the case of eloquent results with joins?

I have a Model (Slide) that uses the column [slug] for routing.  That is set like so:

```
public function getRouteKeyName() {
    return 'slug';
}
```

The same model also uses the boot function to grab a few other pertinent columns from a related categories table/model.

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope('content_type', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('content_types.name', 'Slide')
                ->join('content_categories', 'content.id', '=', 'content_categories.content_id')
                ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'content_categories.category_id')
                ->select('content.*', 'categories.name as category', 'categories.id as category_id');
    });
}
```

The problem is that the categories table also has a [slug] column, which means Laravel's in-built RouteKeyName functionality is sending up an "ambiguous column name" warning upon building out the sql for my editing route.

> Ambiguous column name 'slug'. (SQL: select top 1 [content].*, [categories].[name] as [category], [categories].[id] as [category_id] from [content] inner join [content_types] on [content].[content_type_id] = [content_types].[id] inner join [content_categories] on [content].[id] = [content_categories].[content_id] inner join [categories] on [categories].[id] = [content_categories].[category_id] where [slug] = when-to-decant--33 and [content].[deleted_at] is null and [content_types].[name] = Slide)

I tried modifying the getRouteKeyName method to disambiguate like this:

```
public function getRouteKeyName() {
   return 'content.slug';
}
```

That gets rid of the ambiguous column warning, but throws up a new error about required route parameters missing.

> Missing required parameters for [Route: slide.show] [URI: slides/show/{item}]

I might just be stuck and have to work through the relationship for my Slide categories instead of the join and select method, but I thought I'd see if anyone here on stackoverflow had a work around.

Comment: you need to pass an `id` of `slide` model along with the route, can you show us where you are using the show slide route?

Comment: now your problem is in the route in some other part of the code and not the query

Comment: I do pass the slide along with it.  It doesn't recognize it because of the slug correlation.  I found no solution to the problem, so I ended up removing the join.

Comment: @Psycho - and just for clarification, the problem was not (was never) about the route.  The route was passed the correct slide instance using "route('slide.show', $slide)" -- which worked fine both BEFORE I added the query join on the model and AFTER I removed that join later when I could not resolve the conflicting column name for [slug].

Comment: okay I understand your situation now and probably the solution also. For clarification, did you try to alias `categories.slug as category_slug` and `slide.slug as slide_slug` in your join query? while having your `getRouteKeyName()` return `slug` like you tried

Comment: @Psycho - I don't recall if I tried that specifically as a fix. I wasn't actually selecting and returning the [categories].[slug] at all, which was why it was so frustrating that a conflict was occurring to begin with.  The query was only returning one [slug] field in the dataset. I did try to alias the slug I wanted `slide.slug as slide_slug`, but that didn't resolve the problem.  

As I mentioned, I've recoded the project now, but if I get a chance I'll test that solution out sometime just for curiosity's sake.